# Bootstrap 4 и картинки в колонках

Tags: css, bootstrap, img

Ряд (row) по bootstrap состоит из двух div - col-lg-4 и col-lg-8.
Почему картинка выходит за рамки колонки? Разве она не должна быть в рамках 4-х колонок по bootsrap и автоматический подстраиваться?

[image: Bootstrap 4 и картинки в колонках]

Код

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <div class="left-sidebar_object">
  <img src="img/obects/object-prew.png" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что картинке надо задать класс img-fluid, иначе она не будет подстраиваться под адаптивно изменяемые размеры колонки:

```css
.col-lg-4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <div class="left-sidebar_object">
  <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=235c638201d8844df2ce07356bce48f2-l&n=13" alt="" class="img-fluid">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: класс img-fluid, не сработал почему то. нашел решение css - img {max-widht: 100%}

Comment: @Damir, а как Вы это поняли?

Comment: @humster_spb, смотря какая ж версия bootstrap

Comment: @HamSter, в заголовке написано 4

Comment: @humster_spb, да, не заметила, тогда автор явно где-то просто ошибку допустил, раз не сработал класс

Comment: @HamSter, главное, я же специально в ответе привёл воспроизводимый пример, где всё работает, - спрашивается, для чего старался? :)